# Default value for date is not showing

Tags: html, css, angular, date, datetime

I had tried a few date formats, but neither one worked for me.
The problem is that on edit profile I want to display default values for different fields and default value for date input field is not displaying.

```html
 <input type="date" formControlName="birthdate" value="{{patient.birthdate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}" id="txtDate" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
```

You can see that when I display the date in html it works.
This format is for my angular app `{{patient.birthdate | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}`.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the format

```
date:'yyyy-MM-dd'
```

instead of

```
date:'MM-dd-yyyy'
```

It seems that the input field doesn't show date if not specified in specific format.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can set first value when you init formControl or update existing control.

For example:

```
formControl = new FormControl(this.patient.birthdate);
```

or

```
this.formControl.setValue(this.patient.birthdate)
```

It also works with FromGroup.

Comment: I can`t, because I have some async functions on web api, and my patient is undefined at that moment. The code for formControl is executed first, so as a solution, I initialized every input first with formControl, then I changed default values from html with a ngIf to check if my async function is completed.

Comment: Anyway, all fields, as you can see in the uploaded image have default values, so is a problem only for date.

Comment: If yours async method return Observable, you can update form in subscribe. Just remember to call initialization of form before the subscription.

Comment: Thanks to this, you can avoid a few ifs.